# Kraken API Gateway Container Crashes When Adding TLS Support

Tags: openssl, krakend

My Kraken (version 2) deployment crashes any time I add the TLS key to the config file.

**Step 1:** I generated a public and private key pair using OpenSSL.

```
> openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 4096
> openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
```

**Step 2:** I launched KrakenD inside a container, with the following volume mounts:
`/etc/krakend` to `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/apitest/conf`

***The container does not crash***.

**Step 3:** I shut down the container and add the following to my kraken config file.

```
"tls": {
   "private_key": "/etc/krakend/private-key.pem",
   "public_key": "/etc/krakend/public-key.pem"
}
```

When I relaunch my container, the container crashes. I have checked that the container can read from the location (it's reading the config file, after all).  I validated my JSON file using JSONLint.com, and it's valid.

`kubectl logs...` shows this error: "2022/02/15 16:06:51  ERROR: [tls: failed to find "CERTIFICATE" PEM block in certificate input after skipping PEM blocks of the following types: [PUBLIC KEY]]"

Why is it crashing?  I don't know how to debug it from here.

Should I be using the private key or should I be using a self-signed certificate generated from the private key?

Comment: Could you share the version you are using and the logs of what is happening when it crashes?

Comment: @alo I added the version and the error message in the container logs (version 2 and `022/02/15 16:06:51  ERROR: [tls: failed to find "CERTIFICATE" PEM block in certificate input after skipping PEM blocks of the following types: [PUBLIC KEY]]`)

Comment: I don't know anything about kraken but it looks to me like it is looking for a *certificate* and *not* a public key. Indeed the example on https://www.krakend.io/docs/service-settings/tls/ for the "public_key" setting is "/path/to/cert.pem" suggesting it really wants a certificate for that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the files with the following command and do not manipulate them after generation:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Your Organization/OU=Your Unit/CN=localhost\"
```

After the command, you can copy the files to your image using a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM devopsfaith/krakend

COPY krakend.json .
COPY key.pem .
COPY cert.pem .
```

And build it, e.g.:

```
docker build -t test .
```

If you just run the image, you'll see the permissions error in the log:

```
❯ docker run test                
Parsing configuration file: /etc/krakend/krakend.json
....
2022/02/16 18:54:38  ERROR: [open ./key.pem: permission denied]
2022/02/16 18:54:38  INFO: [Router execution ended]
```

This is because krakend uses the `krakend` user in runtime (not root), and if you just copy the files in the `/etc/krakend` directory it doesn't have access to it.

For instance, if you run docker using the root user the problem would go away:

```
docker run -p "443:8080" --user root test
```

You could also copy the files in /tmp and you would not need the root user at all. There are more ways to fix this, and these are a few examples.

Comment: I think I need to go back to basics:  which do I enter as the `public_key` and which do I enter as the `private_key`?  I tried `key.pem` for the public key and vice versa, but each time, I get an error in the container that says ` ERROR: [open /etc/krakend/key.pem: permission denied]`

Comment: The container crashes immediately and enters a CrashLoopBackOff cycle, so I can't SSH into it.

Comment: I disabled the TLS config that was causing the crash and SSH'd into the container so I could run `ls -la` and view the permissions.

Comment: The permission on key.pem is `-rw-------`

Comment: I have edited my comment so you have more context and get rid of this error.